# Kotlin Proguard rule for enum?

Tags: enums, kotlin, proguard

Hi there can somebody please advise me if there are any specific rules required for Kotlin class with enum? Simple example as

```
data class Passenger(
    var type: Type?,
    var id: Int,
    var age: Int
) {

companion object {

    const val AGE_NOT_SET = -1
}

enum class Type {
    ADULT, CHILD, INFANT
}

constructor() : this(null, 0, 0)
}
```

If object get initialized to `Passenger(CHILD, 123456, 4)` converted to Json and later on parsed back to POJO it will result in `Passenger(null, 0,0)`

I do have

```
-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * { 
    public static **[] values(); public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); 
}
```

in my proguard rules that works for enum in Java but for some reason it fails for Kotlin

Comment: any luck finding the solution?

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you need to keep all public enum class members to avoid this error. This worked for me:

```
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public *;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-keep class Type {
    public *;
}
```

This works for me. If it doesn't work for you, try moving the enum to a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding the following line inside your 'proguard-rules.pro' file. Make sure to replace the 'package.name' part with your own package name.

```
-keepnames class package.name.Type
```